# Error while generating signed apk in Android studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-keystore, signed-apk, keystore-access

Hello I am generating signed apk from Android Studio. But when i try to generate it gives me error. can any one help me to solve this?

Error

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21351122/3395198

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya right now there is use embedded checkbox selected and under that it has this path C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre

Comment: Maybe you've already installed Java and JAVA_HOME path is pointing to `C:\Program Files\Java\bin`. So uncheck default JRE path and set it to `C:\Program Files\Java\bin` in Android Studio like Intellij Amiya pointed out.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i solved it as you said.. but now its giving error in apk generate..

Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageRelease'.
> File 'E:\Android_Project\BPC\BPC\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-release-stripped.ap_' specified for property 'resourceFile' does not exist.

Comment: add `shrinkResources false`

Comment: and what about minify? true or false? seems like 2.3.3 is buggy

Answer (score 1):

I found solution. First i reinstall the updated jdk and jre and then restart. and then copy keytool.exe to path and then change as per @IntelliJ Amiya suggested in comment. Now it works fine for me.